# How to "rollout" a new app to the internal testers list, before automatically being "published" & visible on Google Play?

Tags: publish, google-play-console, rollout

The help text on Google Play Console is confusing. While we can set up a release to rollout for an internal test, it says* that a rollout to any track automatically sets the status to Published, and makes it visible on Google Play.

It must be possible to provision the test release to the internal testers before it is rolled out and visible on Google Play, right? How?

- See "New Apps" at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334282?hl=en&ref_topic=7072031

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion comes from the statement "visible on Google Play". It is visible on Google Play, but only visible to people who are in the internal testers list. No-one else can see it or find it in search results.

The benefit to it being "visible" on Google Play are things which require this, like testing in-app purchases or license verification work.